# Error in ASP.NET MVC Project after Updating NuGet Packages and Bundling Bootstrap

Tags: model-view-controller

I am encountering a

```
System.NullReferenceException
```

when attempting to bundle Bootstrap in my ASP.NET MVC project. This issue arose after updating all NuGet packages. The bundling process seems to work as expected when scripts are included traditionally, but encounters an error when using bundling.

**Error Message:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JSj9.png)

```
`System.NullReferenceException
    HResult=0x80004003
    Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    Source=WebGrease
    StackTrace:
    at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseObjectLiteralProperty(Boolean isBindingPattern)`
```

1. Updated all NuGet packages.
2. Bundling is automatically adding script files in `_layout.cshtml` and `BundleConfig.cs`.
3. Error occurs during runtime.

```
`_layout.cshtml`:
   `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")`
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kDCn.png)

```
`BundleConfig.cs`:

   `bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"));`
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plfii.png)

Confirming that the Bootstrap script files are present in the specified locations.

Traditional inclusion of scripts works without errors.